# google font does not work in rails unless i link to external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, asset-pipeline, google-font-api

I have saved the google font at the url

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7cDroid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic%7cRoboto+Slab:400,100,300,700
```

to

```
app-->assets-->stylesheets-->external-->contemporary_fonts.css.scss
```

Here is my application.css:

```
*= require_tree ./font-awesome
*= require_tree ./external
*= require_tree ./production
*= require_self
*= require custom
*/
```

The css file loads.  I check the page source and the stylesheet is there.  For some reason though, the fonts are not showing up.  If i just include a "link href" to the url, it will work, but i don't want to do that.  I want all of the stylesheets to be hosted on the rails app.

Why is the font not working?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `@import` in your `contemporary_fonts.css.scss`.

```
@import https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700%7cDroid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic%7cRoboto+Slab:400,100,300,700
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve my problem.  I want to keep the css in my application, not call for it when it is launched.